# Query with Dapper ORM very slow

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper, epplus

I am using Dapper to access some data from SQL Server and convert it into a list. It will be loaded from the EPPLUS library to export about 1.8 million rows in Excel.  To overcome the limits of EPPLUS, I divided this into worksheets of 50,000 lines each. The problem is that it takes between 12 and 15 minutes to get the complete list. How can the operation be sped up?

```cs
List<string> query = new List<string>();
List<EntityFramework.Channels>[] array_channel_list = new List<EntityFramework.Channels>[dim];
worker.ReportProgress(60);
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        query.Add("SELECT ID, matricola, disegno, descrizione, nodeid, result, coppia, angolo, prgnr, prgname, date, NomeFile, lastcmd, laststeprow, laststepcolumn, qualitycode, rootobj_ID FROM dbo.Channels where rootobj_ID IN (" + string.Join(",", array_id[i]) + ") ORDER BY ID");
        try {
            worker.ReportProgress(65);
            array_channel_list[i] = conn.Query<EntityFramework.Channels>(query[i], commandTimeout: queryTimeoutInSeconds,buffered:false).ToList();
            
        } catch (SqlException error) {
            Console.WriteLine("Errore: " + error.ToString());
        }
    }
}

worker.ReportProgress(70);
for (int i = 0; i < Number_Worksheet; i++) {
    objWorksheet_channel[i].Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(array_channel_list[i], true);
    objWorksheet_channel[i].DeleteColumn(18);
    objWorksheet_channel[i].Cells.Style.Font.SetFromFont(new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 10));
    //Set the format of date column
    objWorksheet_channel[i].Column(11).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm";
    objWorksheet_channel[i].Cells.AutoFitColumns();
    worker.ReportProgress(80);
    //Format the header    
    //  using (ExcelRange objRange = objWorksheet.Cells["A1:" + Char.ConvertFromUtf32(dtFromGrid.Columns.Count + 64) +"1" ])
    using (ExcelRange objRange = objWorksheet_channel[i].Cells["A1:Q1"]) {
        objRange.Style.Font.Bold = true;
        objRange.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
        objRange.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
        objRange.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        objRange.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue);
        objRange.AutoFilter = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to create an SQL command. Use parameterized statements. See [why it's a bad idea and how to fix it](//bobby-tables.com).

Comment: yes, in SSMS 54 seconds!

Comment: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: [link](https://postimg.cc/vDzTz1Z0)

Comment: Do you have an index on `rootobj_ID` (preferably a clustered index)?

Comment: rootobj_ID is Foreign KEY

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked if you have an index on it.

Comment: yes!i have index on it

Comment: Better process is using SqlBulkCopy to INSERT these values into a separate table, and then JOIN to the table.

Answer (score 2):

Very large `IN` lists usually perform poorly on SQL Server. it's much better to use a Table Valued Parameter, and dump all of the IDs in at once.

First create a table type. I usually keep a few useful ones to hand. Make sure to give it a primary key if possible, as that gets you a free index.

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.IntList AS TABLE (Id int PRIMARY KEY)
```

Then load it using Dapper's `AsTableValuedParameter`

```cs
List<string> query = new List<string>();
List<EntityFramework.Channels>[] array_channel_list = new List<EntityFramework.Channels>[dim];
worker.ReportProgress(60);
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    conn.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    {
        var table = new DataTable { Columns = { { "Id", typeof(int) }, } };

        foreach (var id in array_id[i])
            table.Rows.Add(id);

        try
        {
            const string query = @"
SELECT
  ID, matricola, disegno, descrizione, nodeid, result,
  coppia, angolo, prgnr, prgname, date, NomeFile,
  lastcmd, laststeprow, laststepcolumn, qualitycode, rootobj_ID
FROM dbo.Channels c
WHERE c.rootobj_ID IN (
    SELECT t.Id FROM @tmp
    )
ORDER BY ID;
";

            worker.ReportProgress(65);
            array_channel_list[i] = conn.Query<EntityFramework.Channels>(
              query,
              new { tmp = table.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.IntList") },
              commandTimeout: queryTimeoutInSeconds,
              buffered: false
             ).ToList();
        }
        catch (SqlException error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Errore: " + error.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

If possible, you should remove the `ORDER BY` clause, as that will be causing an extra sort.

You are also going to need an index on `rootobj_ID`. Judging by the amount of other columns you are querying, you probably want to make this a clustered index. Otherwise a non-clustered index will need `INCLUDE` columns of all those that you are selecting.

Comment: Once you've got the table you can possibly also convert this to use a `JOIN`, which could do much better than a large `IN()`. But the table-value param is the main thing, so plus one.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn SQL Server is perfectly capable of transforming between `JOIN` and `IN`, there is no real need to change it. See eg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ca40e939c7410abd92cf9b227ba2c6b